# Scraping book names using BeautifulSoup library returns 0 as output

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape title names from a website but it returns 0 as an output each time. Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.blinkist.com/en/content/topics/listening-en"

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
# print (html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

book_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"data-test-id":"book-card-title"})
print(len(book_titles))

for title in book_titles:
  print(title.text)
```

I was expecting book titles as a result but horribly missing something here

Comment: if you look at the html, there is nothing called "book-card-title"

Answer (score 0):

If [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is an option :

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.blinkist.com/en/content/topics/listening-en"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    
    css = "script[type='application/ld+json']"

    data = json.loads(driver.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, css).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    
titles = [d["name"] for d in data["hasPart"]]
```

Output :

```
# len(titles) # 34

[
    'Crucial Conversations',
    'Just Listen',
    'The Art of Communicating',
    'Talk Lean',
    'The 11 Laws of Likability',
    'Nonviolent Communication',
    ...
]
```